# Remove MVC subdirectories with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove my application and controller directories from my url.

If I type (or am redirected via script) to: **www.example.com/application/controller/main.php**

I need this removed: **application/controller/**

so it only shows: **www.example.com/main.php**

Haven't played much with mod_rewrite, running wamp with rewrite installed.

Been pulling my hair out for half an hour now, Do I need htaccess to do this or can php do it instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are going to downvote at least put an explanation.

Comment: I assume whoever downvoted also voted to close, with this reason: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/controller%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/controller%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /application/controller%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

You can then request `www.example.com/main.php` and as long as `/application/controller/main.php` exists, it'll serve that.

If you need to redirect requests that directly access the controller, then you can add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /application/controller/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```